# CSV uploader throwing errors randomly for identical entries

Tags: magento2, attribute-set

I'm trying to upload 12000 SKU's (1000 at a time) using the CSV uploader.

I'm getting some random errors for identical data.

For example, every cell in the `attribute_set_column` has a 9, but I get this error

> Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set doesn't exist?) in a
>   row(s): 575, 577

Is there any way to fix inconsistencies like this, or at lease get less vague error messages?

Thanks

Comment: Did you happen to see if there are any special characters in the rows 575, 577 in the CSV? If you happen to know the values, try manually editing those cells in the CSV and change it to the require values just to see if there any special characters.

Comment: They both just have a 9. I used the excel option to remove all formatting from the column